# How to create a cross-compilation sysroot for Linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling, rpm, chroot

I'm trying to build a GCC cross-compiler with `--host=x86_64-apple-darwin10` and `--target=ppc64-linux`.

I need to have a sysroot for my target. What I have available to me is an .iso that's designed to boot and setup that target. On it are a giant pile of rpms.

I'd like to know the Linux guru incantations that will unpack the proper rpms into an empty directory on OS X successfully and make that sysroot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to build `rpm2cpio` on OSX, and then unpack thus:

```
mkdir /desired/sysroot && cd /desired/sysroot
for j in /path/to/iso/*.rpm; do
   rpm2cpio $j | cpio -idmB
done
```

But it might be easier to just unpack on a Linux host (perhaps inside a VM).

Comment: This at least seems to have built something useable for me, but I'm pretty sure that any amount of sophisticated scripts in the rpms would have not worked.